# C - programming a makefile and how they work

Tags: c, compilation, makefile

So given three files:

### ***main.h***

```
#include <stdio.h>
void printFunc(*char);
```

---

### ***main.c***

```
    #include "main.h"
    int main(){
        printFunc("Hello World\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

---

### ***printFunc.c***

```
    #include "main.h"
    void printFunc(char *string){
        printf("%s", string);
        return;
    }
```

---

You can compile using gcc on a linux machine as follows:

```
    gcc -g -Wall -c file1.c             //compile but do not link file
    gcc -g -Wall -c file2.c             //same
    gcc file1.o file2.o -o main         //executable "main"
```

or

```
    gcc -g -Wall file1.c file2.c -o main
```

But I am concerned with how the header file gets included. I came across this when I was working on creating a "makefile" when I noticed that some tutorials will do something like this:

```
    main : main.o printFunc.o
            gcc -o main main.o printFunc.o

    main.o : main.c
            gcc -g -Wall -c -o main.o main.c

    printFunc.o : printFunc.c
            gcc -g -Wall -c -o printFunc.o printFunc.c
```

and others will include the header file as a dependent with:

```
    main : main.o printFunc.o  //main.h EDIT
           //commands
    main.o : printFunc.o main.h
           //commands
```

---

### Finally:

So, is it necessary to include the header file as a dependent to the executable? When does the include file get placed within the sources?

And also one could use this command:

```
    executableName : dependencies.o               //and a header file? 
            gcc -g -Wall -o executableSource.c
```

Which could be done with the line:

```
    gcc -g -Wall -o executableName executableSource.c
```

Will the second command be run but the first is shorthand notation?

And finally, I thought the "-o" command was "send output to", if you will. If that way, it seems intuitive to run the command like:

```
    gcc compileThisFile andSendOutputTo thisExecutableFile
    gcc someSource.c          -o            executableFile
```

But with the notation listed above its more like:

```
    gcc sendOutputTo thisExecutableFile fromThisSource
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dependency in Makefile is saying that whenever any of the listed files change, run the command again. It does not mean that the listed file will be included into the compilation or linking. You still need the regular `#include "main.h"` in your sources.

Thus, this works too:

```
printFunc.o : printFunc.c someReadmeFile.txt
        gcc -g -Wall -c -o printFunc.o printFunc.c
```

Whenever `printFunc.c` *or* `someReadmeFile.txt` is updated, `gcc -g -Wall ....` will be executed again.

I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: So the dependencies (printFunc.c and someReadmeFile.txt) are looked at for changes. If changes are found then printFunc.c is recompiled? That's all? I thought it was saying that to compile printFunc.o we *NEED* printFunc.o and someReadmeFile.txt.

Comment: Yup! That's correct. The proper use of it would be to indicate "NEED", but well, they are just tools :)

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense. So if we include no dependencies as in `main : ` followed by its compilation command we will it ever be recompiled after the initial call to make since there are no files to check for changes?

Comment: And I think I was confused because of the notation of the compiling command                       `gcc -g -Wall -o main main.o printFunc.o` where basically we are saying to create main we need the following two object files otherwise we fail.

Comment: To clarify, the dependencies are looked at for _time change_. If `printFunc.c` is _newer_ than `printFunc.o`, the command will run again. So if you open & save `printFunc.c` without any changes (or use the `touch` command, it'll run too.

Comment: `main : ` without any dependency will run every time it's called.

Comment: Great. Thank you! And as an aside, I cannot find much documentation on the -Wall command when compiling. I know that it enables a majority of the warnings when compiling, but how is it broken down? I know there is a -W command, so is -Wall actually (-W)(all) or (-W)(a)(ll) or something else?

Comment: `-Wall` would be (-W)(all), though this should be a new question by itself :-) This should help: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: Thanks so much. And I have one final question: The command `gcc -o executable file1.o file2.o` is the "linking" stage command?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yup - that would be the "linking" stage. Thanks for accepting my answer! :-)

Answer (score 2):

`main : main.o printFun.o main.h` is definitely wrong.  That's saying that the header is a prerequisite for **linking**.  A header is a prerequisite for **compilation**.

Assuming what you really meant was to specify the header as a compilation dependency (e.g. `printFunc.o : printFunc.c printFunc.h`), this means that if the header changes, the object file will be automatically regenerated.  If you don't, then it won't.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I updated the OP but your answer makes it much clearer now. So the object files are compiled from the source files(and other dependencies including header files) and then linked together to form the executable?

Comment: But either way, the tutorial here http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/ includes the header file as a dependency for the object files while others do not. The code above works fine without explicitly including the header file as a dependent (in the makefile).